# break for loop and return value , recursive function in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

i have a recursive function to find key and return his value, this is my code

```
$scope.findSelected = function (object, name){
            //var key = '';
            for (var i =0 ; i< object.length; i++){
               var children =object[i];
                var vName =children.Value.Name;
                if(vName=== name ){
                    var key=children.Value.Key;
                    break;


                }else {
                     key = $scope.findSelected(children.Children, name);
                }
            }
            return key;
        };
```

where vName === name i have to return key, but not work the loop play again, I think I've any dodgy thing and function return unidentified

Comment: Notice that a `return` only returns from the current call of the function, not the uppermost recursive one? And `break` only breaks from the current loop, not all loops in your recursion?

Comment: if you inside recursion you need also check what return  `$scope.findSelected` in _else_ branch and if it return not undefined - also break loop

Comment: if someone can change my code to the function works properly

Comment: It's better if people teach you to find the problems yourself, so that you can fix your own code in the future.

Comment: so if someone can explain me more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following. It checks at the end of each iteration if key has been set and if so will return it.  This will also "bubble up" from lower levels of recursion.  The search order is depth-first.

```js
$scope.findSelected = function (object, name){
    var key;

    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
         var children =object[i];
         var vName = children.Value.Name;

         if(vName === name ){
              key = children.Value.Key;
         } else {
              key = $scope.findSelected(children.Children, name);
         }

         if(key) return key;
    }
};
```